# Qt 4.8, Visual Studio 2013 compiling error

Tags: qt, visual-studio-2012, compiler-construction, qt4, visual-studio-2013

Am folowing this [tutorial](http://menatronics.blogspot.fr/2012/12/compiling-qt-for-visual-studio-2012.html) to compile Qt 4.8 with visual Studio 2013 but after running nmake i get:

```
C:\Qt\4.8.5.src\src\3rdparty\javascriptcore\JavaScriptCore\wtf/MathExtras.h(103) : error C2491: 'round' : definition of dllimport function not allowed
C:\Qt\4.8.5.src\src\3rdparty\javascriptcore\JavaScriptCore\wtf/MathExtras.h(110) : error C2491: 'roundf' : definition of dllimport function not allowed
C:\Qt\4.8.5.src\src\3rdparty\javascriptcore\JavaScriptCore\wtf/MathExtras.h(128) : error C2084: function 'bool signbit(double)' already has a body
        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\INCLUDE\math.h(324) : see previous definition of 'signbit'
c:\qt\4.8.5.src\src\3rdparty\javascriptcore\javascriptcore\runtime\JSValue.h(615) : error C2264: 'signbit' : error in function definition or declaration; function not called
c:\qt\4.8.5.src\src\3rdparty\javascriptcore\javascriptcore\runtime\JSValue.h(696) : error C2264: 'signbit' : error in function definition or declaration; function not called
JSCallbackConstructor.cpp
C:\Qt\4.8.5.src\src\3rdparty\javascriptcore\JavaScriptCore\wtf/MathExtras.h(103) : error C2491: 'round' : definition of dllimport function not allowed
C:\Qt\4.8.5.src\src\3rdparty\javascriptcore\JavaScriptCore\wtf/MathExtras.h(110) : error C2491: 'roundf' : definition of dllimport function not allowed
C:\Qt\4.8.5.src\src\3rdparty\javascriptcore\JavaScriptCore\wtf/MathExtras.h(128) : error C2084: function 'bool signbit(double)' already has a body
        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\INCLUDE\math.h(324) : see previous definition of 'signbit'
c:\qt\4.8.5.src\src\3rdparty\javascriptcore\javascriptcore\runtime\JSValue.h(615) : error C2264: 'signbit' : error in function definition or declaration; function not called
c:\qt\4.8.5.src\src\3rdparty\javascriptcore\javascriptcore\runtime\JSValue.h(696) : error C2264: 'signbit' : error in function definition or declaration; function not called
JSCallbackFunction.cpp
C:\Qt\4.8.5.src\src\3rdparty\javascriptcore\JavaScriptCore\wtf/MathExtras.h(103) : error C2491: 'round' : definition of dllimport function not allowed
C:\Qt\4.8.5.src\src\3rdparty\javascriptcore\JavaScriptCore\wtf/MathExtras.h(110) : error C2491: 'roundf' : definition of dllimport function not allowed
C:\Qt\4.8.5.src\src\3rdparty\javascriptcore\JavaScriptCore\wtf/MathExtras.h(128) : error C2084: function 'bool signbit(double)' already has a body
        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\INCLUDE\math.h(324) : see previous definition of 'signbit'
c:\qt\4.8.5.src\src\3rdparty\javascriptcore\javascriptcore\runtime\JSValue.h(615) : error C2264: 'signbit' : error in function definition or declaration; function not called
c:\qt\4.8.5.src\src\3rdparty\javascriptcore\javascriptcore\runtime\JSValue.h(696) : error C2264: 'signbit' : error in function definition or declaration; function not called
JSCallbackObject.cpp
C:\Qt\4.8.5.src\src\3rdparty\javascriptcore\JavaScriptCore\wtf/MathExtras.h(103) : error C2491: 'round' : definition of dllimport function not allowed
C:\Qt\4.8.5.src\src\3rdparty\javascriptcore\JavaScriptCore\wtf/MathExtras.h(110) : error C2491: 'roundf' : definition of dllimport function not allowed
C:\Qt\4.8.5.src\src\3rdparty\javascriptcore\JavaScriptCore\wtf/MathExtras.h(128) : error C2084: function 'bool signbit(double)' already has a body
        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\INCLUDE\math.h(324) : see previous definition of 'signbit'
c:\qt\4.8.5.src\src\3rdparty\javascriptcore\javascriptcore\runtime\JSValue.h(615) : error C2264: 'signbit' : error in function definition or declaration; function not called
c:\qt\4.8.5.src\src\3rdparty\javascriptcore\javascriptcore\runtime\JSValue.h(696) : error C2264: 'signbit' : error in function definition or declaration; function not called
JSClassRef.cpp
C:\Qt\4.8.5.src\src\3rdparty\javascriptcore\JavaScriptCore\wtf/MathExtras.h(103) : error C2491: 'round' : definition of dllimport function not allowed
C:\Qt\4.8.5.src\src\3rdparty\javascriptcore\JavaScriptCore\wtf/MathExtras.h(110) : error C2491: 'roundf' : definition of dllimport function not allowed
C:\Qt\4.8.5.src\src\3rdparty\javascriptcore\JavaScriptCore\wtf/MathExtras.h(128) : error C2084: function 'bool signbit(double)' already has a body
        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\INCLUDE\math.h(324) : see previous definition of 'signbit'
c:\qt\4.8.5.src\src\3rdparty\javascriptcore\javascriptcore\runtime\JSValue.h(615) : error C2264: 'signbit' : error in function definition or declaration; function not called
c:\qt\4.8.5.src\src\3rdparty\javascriptcore\javascriptcore\runtime\JSValue.h(696) : error C2264: 'signbit' : error in function definition or declaration; function not called
JSContextRef.cpp
C:\Qt\4.8.5.src\src\3rdparty\javascriptcore\JavaScriptCore\wtf/MathExtras.h(103) : error C2491: 'round' : definition of dllimport function not allowed
C:\Qt\4.8.5.src\src\3rdparty\javascriptcore\JavaScriptCore\wtf/MathExtras.h(110) : error C2491: 'roundf' : definition of dllimport function not allowed
C:\Qt\4.8.5.src\src\3rdparty\javascriptcore\JavaScriptCore\wtf/MathExtras.h(128) : error C2084: function 'bool signbit(double)' already has a body
        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\INCLUDE\math.h(324) : see previous definition of 'signbit'
c:\qt\4.8.5.src\src\3rdparty\javascriptcore\javascriptcore\runtime\JSValue.h(615) : error C2264: 'signbit' : error in function definition or declaration; function not called
c:\qt\4.8.5.src\src\3rdparty\javascriptcore\javascriptcore\runtime\JSValue.h(696) : error C2264: 'signbit' : error in function definition or declaration; function not called
JSObjectRef.cpp
C:\Qt\4.8.5.src\src\3rdparty\javascriptcore\JavaScriptCore\wtf/MathExtras.h(103) : error C2491: 'round' : definition of dllimport function not allowed
C:\Qt\4.8.5.src\src\3rdparty\javascriptcore\JavaScriptCore\wtf/MathExtras.h(110) : error C2491: 'roundf' : definition of dllimport function not allowed
C:\Qt\4.8.5.src\src\3rdparty\javascriptcore\JavaScriptCore\wtf/MathExtras.h(128) : error C2084: function 'bool signbit(double)' already has a body
        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\INCLUDE\math.h(324) : see previous definition of 'signbit'
c:\qt\4.8.5.src\src\3rdparty\javascriptcore\javascriptcore\runtime\JSValue.h(615) : error C2264: 'signbit' : error in function definition or declaration; function not called
c:\qt\4.8.5.src\src\3rdparty\javascriptcore\javascriptcore\runtime\JSValue.h(696) : error C2264: 'signbit' : error in function definition or declaration; function not called
JSStringRef.cpp
JSValueRef.cpp
C:\Qt\4.8.5.src\src\3rdparty\javascriptcore\JavaScriptCore\wtf/MathExtras.h(103) : error C2491: 'round' : definition of dllimport function not allowed
C:\Qt\4.8.5.src\src\3rdparty\javascriptcore\JavaScriptCore\wtf/MathExtras.h(110) : error C2491: 'roundf' : definition of dllimport function not allowed
C:\Qt\4.8.5.src\src\3rdparty\javascriptcore\JavaScriptCore\wtf/MathExtras.h(128) : error C2084: function 'bool signbit(double)' already has a body
        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\INCLUDE\math.h(324) : see previous definition of 'signbit'
c:\qt\4.8.5.src\src\3rdparty\javascriptcore\javascriptcore\runtime\JSValue.h(615) : error C2264: 'signbit' : error in function definition or declaration; function not called
c:\qt\4.8.5.src\src\3rdparty\javascriptcore\javascriptcore\runtime\JSValue.h(696) : error C2264: 'signbit' : error in function definition or declaration; function not called
OpaqueJSString.cpp
C:\Qt\4.8.5.src\src\3rdparty\javascriptcore\JavaScriptCore\wtf/MathExtras.h(103) : error C2491: 'round' : definition of dllimport function not allowed
C:\Qt\4.8.5.src\src\3rdparty\javascriptcore\JavaScriptCore\wtf/MathExtras.h(110) : error C2491: 'roundf' : definition of dllimport function not allowed
C:\Qt\4.8.5.src\src\3rdparty\javascriptcore\JavaScriptCore\wtf/MathExtras.h(128) : error C2084: function 'bool signbit(double)' already has a body
        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\INCLUDE\math.h(324) : see previous definition of 'signbit'
c:\qt\4.8.5.src\src\3rdparty\javascriptcore\javascriptcore\runtime\JSValue.h(615) : error C2264: 'signbit' : error in function definition or declaration; function not called
c:\qt\4.8.5.src\src\3rdparty\javascriptcore\javascriptcore\runtime\JSValue.h(696) : error C2264: 'signbit' : error in function definition or declaration; function not called
Generating Code...
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\BIN\cl.EXE"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\BIN\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'cd' : return code '0x2'
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To fix 'round' and 'roundf' errors replace (lines 103 and 110):

```
static double round(double num)
static float roundf(float num)
```

with:

```
static inline double round(double num)
static inline float roundf(float num)
```

To fix 'signbit' error enclose it with following macro (line 128):

```
#if _MSC_VER < 1800
inline bool signbit(double num) { return _copysign(1.0, num) < 0; }
#endif
```

Comment: Better yet, use the official [patch](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtscript/commit/24d678ce9c3996f46d1069c2b1193e7ec1083fc8).

Comment: I tested both patches from JPaget and Zdenik and they don't work in Qt 4.8.6. This is the only working answer.

Comment: Based on extended C99 library in VS2013 - see article [C99 library support in Visual Studio 2013](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2013/07/19/c99-library-support-in-visual-studio-2013/)  enclose old implementation with code: `#if _MSC_VER < 1800 ... #endif`

Answer (score 7):

Use the official [patch](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtscript/commit/24d678ce9c3996f46d1069c2b1193e7ec1083fc8) for VS 2013 compatibility.

Comment: The full patch is [here](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtdeclarative/commit/a3f01331263eddbc502fb88734568ac38df5e316)

Answer (score 2):

Have you run "vcvars32.bat" before compiling?
It seems the environment variables of VC++ are not appropriately set.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f2ccy3wt.aspx for informations about the environment of VC++.

bye

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you do not use Visual Studio 2012 but 2013. VS 2012 is VS11 while VS 2013 is VS12 and your path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0" belongs to VS 2013.

The core problem however is that VS 2013 is C99 compliant which causes problems in the V8 engine and javascriptcore.

There is currently no solution but manual patching.

Answer (score 2):

The two patches proposed above were not enough. In my case, after applying them to Qt 4.8.5 I got another error:

```
HashSet.h(180) : error C2664: 'std::pair<WTF::HashTableConstIteratorAdapter<WTF::HashTable<void *,void *,WTF::IdentityExtractor<void *>,WTF::PtrHash<JSC::EncodedJSValue>,WTF::HashTraits<JS
C::EncodedJSValue>,WTF::HashTraits<JSC::EncodedJSValue>>,void *>,bool>::pair(const std::pair<WTF::HashTableConstIteratorAdapter<WTF::HashTable<void *,void *,WTF::IdentityExtractor<void *>,WTF::P
trHash<JSC::EncodedJSValue>,WTF::HashTraits<JSC::EncodedJSValue>,WTF::HashTraits<JSC::EncodedJSValue>>,void *>,bool> &)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'std::pair<WTF::HashTableIterator<Key,Va
lue,Extractor,HashFunctions,Traits,KeyTraits>,bool>' to 'const std::pair<WTF::HashTableConstIteratorAdapter<WTF::HashTable<void *,void *,WTF::IdentityExtractor<void *>,WTF::PtrHash<JSC::EncodedJ
SValue>,WTF::HashTraits<JSC::EncodedJSValue>,WTF::HashTraits<JSC::EncodedJSValue>>,void *>,bool> &'                                                                                               
        with                                                                                                                                                                                      
        [                                                                                                                                                                                         
            Key=void *                                                                                                                                                                            
,            Value=void *                                                                                                                                                                         
,            Extractor=WTF::IdentityExtractor<void *>                                                                                                                                             
,            HashFunctions=WTF::PtrHash<JSC::EncodedJSValue>                                                                                                                                      
,            Traits=WTF::HashTraits<JSC::EncodedJSValue>                                                                                                                                          
,            KeyTraits=WTF::HashTraits<JSC::EncodedJSValue>                                                                                                                                       
        ]                                                                                                                                                                                         
        Reason: cannot convert from 'std::pair<WTF::HashTableIterator<Key,Value,Extractor,HashFunctions,Traits,KeyTraits>,bool>' to 'const std::pair<WTF::HashTableConstIteratorAdapter<WTF::HashT
able<void *,void *,WTF::IdentityExtractor<void *>,WTF::PtrHash<JSC::EncodedJSValue>,WTF::HashTraits<JSC::EncodedJSValue>,WTF::HashTraits<JSC::EncodedJSValue>>,void *>,bool>'                     
        with                                                                                                                                                                                      
        [                                                                                                                                                                                         
            Key=void *                                                                                                                                                                            
,            Value=void *                                                                                                                                                                         
,            Extractor=WTF::IdentityExtractor<void *>                                                                                                                                             
,            HashFunctions=WTF::PtrHash<JSC::EncodedJSValue>                                                                                                                                      
,            Traits=WTF::HashTraits<JSC::EncodedJSValue>                                                                                                                                          
,            KeyTraits=WTF::HashTraits<JSC::EncodedJSValue>                                                                                                                                       
        ]                                                                                                                                                                                         
        No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called                                                                          
        .\wtf/HashSet.h(179) : while compiling class template member function 'std::pair<WTF::HashTableConstIteratorAdapter<WTF::HashTable<void *,void *,WTF::IdentityExtractor<void *>,WTF::PtrHa
sh<JSC::EncodedJSValue>,WTF::HashTraits<JSC::EncodedJSValue>,WTF::HashTraits<JSC::EncodedJSValue>>,void *>,bool> WTF::HashSet<void *,WTF::PtrHash<JSC::EncodedJSValue>,WTF::HashTraits<JSC::Encode
dJSValue>>::add(void *const &)'
```

Solution was to grab 3 files from Git Qt4 repository:

/src/3rdparty/webkit/Source/JavaScriptCore/wtf/HashSet.h
https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/mi-clone/raw/b45cc6bba9f85497eedf10cb5969d24273cb11db:src/3rdparty/webkit/Source/JavaScriptCore/wtf/HashSet.h

/src/3rdparty/webkit/Source/JavaScriptCore/wtf/MathExtras.h
https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/mi-clone/raw/b45cc6bba9f85497eedf10cb5969d24273cb11db:src/3rdparty/webkit/Source/JavaScriptCore/wtf/MathExtras.h

/src/3rdparty/javascriptcore/JavaScriptCore/wtf/MathExtras.h
https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/mi-clone/raw/b45cc6bba9f85497eedf10cb5969d24273cb11db:src/3rdparty/javascriptcore/JavaScriptCore/wtf/MathExtras.h

Comment: For clarity, I relink the proposed patches in question comments:
https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtscript/commit/24d678ce9c3996f46d1069c2b1193e7ec1083fc8 and https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtdeclarative/commit/a3f01331263eddbc502fb88734568ac38df5e316

Comment: Since the gitorious site with patches is offline for days (migrating stuff), can someone please send me the patched file for /src/3rdparty/**webkit**/Source/JavaScriptCore/wtf/HashSet.h, since this bug is still **not** fixed in qt 4.8.6 (allthough /src/3rdparty/**javascriptcore**/JavaScriptCore/wtf/HashSet.h compiles). Thanksalot, Hermann

Answer (score 0):

@AppDealer's awnser works, if you have to apply it to both instances of the `MathExtras.h` file. (one in `JavaScriptCore` and another in `Webkit`  After 
that you will run into a `HashSet` build problem.

```
No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called .\wtf/HashSet.h
```

Both these issues are fixes with the [patch](https://bugreports.qt.io/secure/attachment/41874/qt-4.8.6-msvc2013-fix.patch) that can be found on [this issue](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-38025).