# Qt 4.8.6 for VS 2013 fails in Release Mode

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt

I have 'successfully' compiled QT 4.8.6 for VS 2013 using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18080625/qt-4-8-visual-studio-2013-compiling-error) answer. Everything works fine when I compile my code in debug mode but I get weird memory or heap overflow errors in release mode (e.g. when using the Qt function 'toStdString' see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35311710/qt-call-fails-in-release-mode) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34675051/buffer-overrun-using-qt-threads-and-signals) question).

For instance a tiny application containing just this code fails in release mode in function _free_base at HeapFree when toStdString() is called:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::string s = "thisisaveryveryverylongstring";
    QString str = QString::fromStdString(s);
    std::string s2 = str.toStdString();
    return 0;
}
```

Is there anything else I need to adjust when compiling QT 4.8.6 for VS 2013? Change the QMAKESPEC environment variable? Or anything else that comes to mind that would cause this behaviour? Maybe an issue with the VS project configuration?

Thanks!

Comment: I can say this (using the patch to build qt for VS2013) works for me and has worked for me for a long time. No problems at all in debug or release mode. I have several applications at work that I build with this.

Comment: @drescherjm thanks for your response. do you mean this patch: https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtdeclarative/commit/a3f01331263eddbc502fb88734568ac38df5e316?

Comment: @drescherjm or this one: https://github.com/appleseedhq/appleseed/wiki/Making-Qt-4.8.6-compile-with-Visual-Studio-2013

Comment: @hyde I wrote a tiny example program and updated the question accordingly.

Comment: I've seen problems like this when the Qt libraries were compiled with a different version of the compiler than the compiler used to compile the Qt app.  Dunno if that's the problem here, but I thought I'd mention it.  The symptom is that if memory is allocated inside the Qt library and then freed by code compiled into the app (or vice-versa), the heap gets corrupted, since the heap data structures used by the two different compilers are different and incompatible with each other.

Comment: Hi @JeremyFriesner thanks. How to I make sure the same compiler is used? I used the VS2013 x86 Native Tools Command Prompt to compile Qt how can I find out which compiler is used in VS?